# facebook event create in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Following is the code that I did to create a facebook event, however this code does not work, no compile or run time errors. I have written the method and called the method on button click event.

```
public class createEvent extends Activity implements OnClickListener

{
    private Button btnCreateEven;
    private TextView txteventName;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    private String eventID="";
    private Facebook facebookatEventCreate;
    private String eventName = "";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static String appId = "392736034134808";



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.create_event);
            //problem - unable to start activity when setListeners() is uncommented 
           initialize(); 
           setListeners();
        }




        private void initialize()
        {            
            //facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
            facebookatEventCreate = new Facebook(appId);
            mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebookatEventCreate);
            btnCreateEven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_createEvent);
            txteventName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_eventName);
        }


        private void setListeners()
        {

            btnCreateEven.setOnClickListener(this);

        }




        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.btn_createEvent:
                    createEvents();
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }



        /**
         * Creates a new event.
         * 
         * 
         * 
         */

        private void createEvents()
        {
            try
            {                   


                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("name", "test test test");
                params.putString("start_time", "2013-12-02T18:00:00+0530");
                params.putString("end_time", "2013-12-02T20:00:00+0530");
                params.putString("description", "This is test description 10/12/2012");
                params.putString("location", "Mount Lavinia");
                //params.putString("location_id", "");
                params.putString("privacy_type", "OPEN");
                params.putString("picture", "/sdcard/cmd.png");
                mAsyncRunner.request("me/events", params, "POST", new RequestListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String response, Object state)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject event = new JSONObject(response);
                            eventID = event.getString("id");
                            Log.d("createEvent:createEvent", "Event ID->" + eventID);

                           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Event Created!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }





}
```

Please tell me the reason for this, any comments are welcome!

Comment: please make more use of Logs to see where the problem occurs. We cannot help you this blind.

Comment: Thank you, I observed log cat during the button click event, it gives me only this: "1D/dalvikvm(2063): GC_CONCURRENT freed 223K, 4% free 7846K/8135K, paused 12ms+44ms"

Comment: Yeah that is GC.I am talking about Log.i("",""); Add them at specific places to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you authenticating the user anywhere.  You can read about how to do that here: [Facebook Authentication for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/)

If you've already authenticated the user, you need to save the auth token for when you create a new Facebook object.  You can readd the access token using:

```
facebookatEventCreate.setAccessToken(authToken);
facebookatEventCreate.setAccessExpires(unixTime);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I authenticate the user in the main activity and I then move to my second activity -> creatEvent. Is it necessary to authenticate in this activity as well?

Comment: I added the following code inside createEvent():
 mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                String accessToken = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
                facebookatEventCreate.setAccessToken(accessToken);

Still no result, no errors, no event created, please tell me if I have done it wrong, thank you!

Comment: Do you request the "create_event" permission when you auth?

Comment: yes I request, and thank you, now the event gets created, but I had to copy paste the entire code that I used to authenticate in the mainActivity class inside createEvent() as well. Isn't there a short way path that I can used without writing the whole code again to login?

Once again, thank you very much for showing me the correct path -> authentication.......

Comment: You might need to set the expiration date as well.